# Mui Theme Overriding

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following generated MUI component from Mui DatePicker:

```html
<span class="my-theme-MuiTypography-root my-theme-MuiTypography-caption my-theme-MuiDayCalendar-weekdayLabel css-1mln09i-MuiTypography-root-MuiDayCalendar-weekdayLabel" role="columnheader" aria-label="Wednesday">W</span>
```

Which corresponds to the "day of the week" header in the calendar. Due to a conflict in my theme, it is the same color as the background and so the words are not visible. How can I override the theme to change the color of the text in this generated nested component? "my-theme" is the theme prefix.

Comment: Do you actually need to modify the theme? The answer may be yes, but not necessarily. The sx prop is useful in situations for one-off styling adjustments as well. See this page on mui’s site - adjusting the theme is just one of several ways to customize mui for your needs https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/

Comment: @AdamJenkins I know about the sx prop; unfortunately, the DatePicker component does not seem to expose an API to customize the weekday headers based on their documentation. Using sx on the DatePicker component will not work.

Comment: I think you can use the props for slots, slotProps or components overrides to get this done if this is the component you’re using https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/. Consider passing an sx prop to your toolbar slot, for example. I’ll see if I can whip up a stack blitz in a few

Comment: @AdamJenkins I tried to do it with slots and slot props as well, but was having trouble identifying the correct component :( would appreciate help if it is possible!

Comment: Turns out you can do it via the sx prop - this is just an example - you can target whatever internal class you need: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tcky6a?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can override the color of the text in this generated nested component by using the withStyles higher-order component provided by Material-UI. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  weekdayLabel: {
    color: 'your-desired-color',
  },
};

const WeekdayLabel = withStyles(styles)(({ classes, ...otherProps }) => (
  <span
    className={`${classes.weekdayLabel} my-theme-MuiTypography-root my-theme-MuiTypography-caption my-theme-MuiDayCalendar-weekdayLabel css-1mln09i-MuiTypography-root-MuiDayCalendar-weekdayLabel`}
    {...otherProps}
  />
));
```